# Vagrant/puPHPet server works for a few minutes then stops responding

Tags: vagrant, puphpet

I've created a Vagrant/puPHPet server which starts up fine and I can browse to the web server and access MySQL through Adminer -- for a few minutes.  Then I get connection time-out errors and am forced to *vagrant halt* and *vagrant up* again.  This server was working great until, for some reason, I started getting session errors which caused me to *vagrant destroy* and rebuild.

Curiously, I can still ping the domain name (which I've mapped locally using my hosts file) and I can also *vagrant ssh* into the box as needed. Furthermore, I can access the /var/www/html/index.html page by browsing to the IP address, indicating that Apache is actually running properly.

Here's my config.yaml:

```
---
vagrantfile-local:
    vm:
        box: puphpet/centos65-x64
        box_url: puphpet/centos65-x64
        hostname: ''
        memory: '1024'
        cpus: '1'
        chosen_provider: vmware_fusion
        network:
            private_network: 172.16.44.130
            forwarded_port:
                NGb9G9AKiieA:
                    host: '7105'
                    guest: '22'
        post_up_message: ''
        provider:
            virtualbox:
                modifyvm:
                    natdnshostresolver1: on
            vmware:
                numvcpus: 1
            parallels:
                cpus: 1
        provision:
            puppet:
                manifests_path: puphpet/puppet
                manifest_file: site.pp
                module_path: puphpet/puppet/modules
                options:
                    - '--verbose'
                    - '--hiera_config /vagrant/puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml'
                    - '--parser future'
        synced_folder:
            OLYbzo4krRFL:
                owner: www-data
                group: www-data
                source: '/Users/Sean/Documents/Websites/RE Lynx Git'
                target: /var/www/relynx.dev/public_html
                sync_type: default
                rsync:
                    args:
                        - '--verbose'
                        - '--archive'
                        - '-z'
                    exclude:
                        - .vagrant/
                    auto: 'false'
            v2MPTOQwLJ9t:
                owner: www-data
                group: www-data
                source: '/Users/Sean/Documents/Websites/Trouble Ticket v3'
                target: /var/www/troubleticket.dev/public_html
                sync_type: default
                rsync:
                    auto: 'false'
        usable_port_range:
            start: 10200
            stop: 10500
    ssh:
        host: null
        port: null
        private_key_path: null
        username: vagrant
        guest_port: null
        keep_alive: true
        forward_agent: false
        forward_x11: false
        shell: 'bash -l'
    vagrant:
        host: detect
server:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
users_groups:
    install: '1'
    groups: {  }
    users: {  }
cron:
    install: '1'
    jobs: {  }
firewall:
    install: '1'
    rules: {  }
apache:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        user: www-data
        group: www-data
        default_vhost: true
        manage_user: false
        manage_group: false
        sendfile: 0
    modules:
        - rewrite
    vhosts:
        imc73bzqik3f:
            servername: relynx.dev
            serveraliases:
                - www.relynx.dev
            docroot: /var/www/relynx.dev/public_html
            port: '80'
            setenv:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            directories:
                1qhlbhns5682:
                    provider: directory
                    path: /var/www/relynx.dev/public_html
                    options:
                        - Indexes
                        - FollowSymlinks
                        - MultiViews
                    allow_override:
                        - All
                    require:
                        - all
                        - granted
                    custom_fragment: ''
            engine: php
            custom_fragment: ''
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_chain: ''
            ssl_certs_dir: ''
        iawfvimtqhj3:
            servername: troubleticket.dev
            serveraliases:
                - www.troubleticket.dev
            docroot: /var/www/troubleticket.dev/public_html
            port: '80'
            directories:
                nzkzsjt6eeuh:
                    provider: directory
                    path: ''
                    options:
                        - Indexes
                        - FollowSymlinks
                        - MultiViews
                    allow_override:
                        - All
                    require:
                        - all
                        - granted
                    custom_fragment: ''
            engine: php
            custom_fragment: ''
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_chain: ''
            ssl_certs_dir: ''
    mod_pagespeed: 0
nginx:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        default_vhost: 1
        proxy_buffer_size: 128k
        proxy_buffers: '4 256k'
    upstreams: {  }
    vhosts:
        risjadwc5osq:
            proxy: ''
            server_name: awesome.dev
            server_aliases:
                - www.awesome.dev
            www_root: /var/www/awesome
            listen_port: '80'
            location: \.php$
            index_files:
                - index.html
                - index.htm
                - index.php
            envvars:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            engine: php
            client_max_body_size: 1m
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
php:
    install: '1'
    version: '56'
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    modules:
        php:
            - cli
            - intl
            - mcrypt
        pear: {  }
        pecl:
            - pecl_http
    ini:
        display_errors: On
        error_reporting: '-1'
        session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
    timezone: America/Chicago
    mod_php: 0
hhvm:
    install: '0'
    nightly: 0
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    settings:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        port: '9000'
    ini:
        display_errors: On
        error_reporting: '-1'
    timezone: null
xdebug:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        xdebug.default_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_autostart: '0'
        xdebug.remote_connect_back: '1'
        xdebug.remote_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_handler: dbgp
        xdebug.remote_port: '9000'
xhprof:
    install: '0'
wpcli:
    install: '0'
    version: v0.17.1
drush:
    install: '0'
    version: 6.3.0
ruby:
    install: '1'
    versions: {  }
nodejs:
    install: '0'
    npm_packages: {  }
python:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
    versions: {  }
mysql:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        override_options: {  }
        root_password: **REMOVED**
    adminer: '1'
    databases:
        9pj8tSwHkENO:
            grant:
                - ALL
            name: **REMOVED**
            host: localhost
            user: **REMOVED**
            password: '**REMOVED**'
            sql_file: /var/www/relynx.dev/public_html/rladmin_rladmin_2.sql
        BHfYQJD10FjP:
            grant:
                - ALL
            name: **REMOVED**
            host: localhost
            user: **REMOVED**
            password: '**REMOVED**'
            sql_file: /var/www/relynx.dev/public_html/rladmin_rlhpsi_2.sql
postgresql:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        root_password: '123'
        user_group: postgres
        encoding: UTF8
        version: '9.3'
    databases: {  }
    adminer: 0
mariadb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        override_options: {  }
        root_password: '123'
        version: '10.0'
    adminer: 0
    databases: {  }
sqlite:
    install: '0'
    adminer: 0
    databases: {  }
mongodb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        auth: 1
        port: '27017'
    databases: {  }
redis:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        conf_port: '6379'
mailcatcher:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        smtp_ip: 0.0.0.0
        smtp_port: 1025
        http_ip: 0.0.0.0
        http_port: '1080'
        mailcatcher_path: /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/default
        from_email_method: inline
beanstalkd:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        listenaddress: 0.0.0.0
        listenport: '13000'
        maxjobsize: '65535'
        maxconnections: '1024'
        binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
        binlogfsync: null
        binlogsize: '10485760'
    beanstalk_console: 0
    binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
rabbitmq:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        port: '5672'
elastic_search:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 1.4.1
        java_install: true
solr:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 4.10.2
        port: '8984'
```

Comment: Honestly with issues like this and not knowing enough about vagrant etc I would recommend you just start from scratch and use PuPHPet to rebuild a new file. It will resolve these issues and any other ones that may arise. Also make sure all relevant software is up to date.

Comment: Might I recommend not using adminer? Try using a stand-alone software for DBMS administration and connect via SSH. I have been using vagrant in this suggested model for a while with no issues.

Comment: @SamV That's what I ended up doing, just blowing away the thing and starting over and it seems more stable this time.

Comment: @SeanCunningham posted an answer so this can be closed, to actively figure out the issue you would need SSH access which is not exactly an option..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly with issues like this and not knowing enough about vagrant etc I would recommend you just start from scratch and use PuPHPet to rebuild a new file. It will resolve these issues and any other ones that may arise.

Also make sure all relevant software is up to date.